# face detection program with Qt or boost?

Tags: qt, boost

i wanna to program a real,fast and thoroughgoing face detection application , and don't know which is the best for it.

Qt or Boost?

i know the Qt has the great documents , but which is the powerful?

Regards

Comment: Qt and Boost are not alternatives to each others... Some features may overlap or even conflict, but overall they cover very different areas of applicaton programming, and can be used together. This question does not make any more sense than "what is more powerful, a hammer or a saw?". And neither covers face recoqnition... Try OpenCV for that, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For advanced image analyzing stuff, try [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). Qt or Boost have nothing to do with what you're trying to do, though you can use both together with OpenCV if you need to.

Comment: thanks.is there any example in OpenCV for face detecting?

Comment: @AbbasFarahmand Probably there are examples, try googling "opencv face detection"...